# Solicitar dados de acesso quando algum dado estiver errado

Tags: java

Alguém poderia me informar uma maneira de fazer a seguinte coisa: Após o erro de senha ou usuário, ou os dois, o usuário retornasse para a primeira pergunta, no caso: "Qual o usuário?" para que pudesse tentar novamente.

```
package SistemaLogineRegistro;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Usuario um = new Usuario();
        um.setUsuario("Yuri", "123123yuri");
        um.getUsuario();
        um.getSenha();

        int tentativa = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Qual o usuario?");
        String usuario = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Qual a senha?");
        String senha = s.nextLine();

            if (usuario.equalsIgnoreCase(um.getUsuario()) && senha.equals(um.getSenha())) {
                System.out.println("Logado com sucesso!");
            }
            else if(!usuario.equals(um.usuario)) {
                System.err.println("Usuario incorreto");
                tentativa += 1;

            } else if (!senha.equals(um.senha)) {
                tentativa += 1;
                System.err.println("Senha incorreta");
            } else if (!senha.equals(um.senha) && !usuario.equals(um.usuario)) {
                tentativa += 1;
                System.out.println("Usuario e senha Incorretos !");
            }else if(tentativa >= 5){
                System.err.println("Você excedeu o Limite de ERRO ! (5) Tentativas");
            }   

        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Já estudou sobre laços de repetição?

Comment: Ja estudei laços de repetição, Porém acredito que dê pra fazer com do while porem n sei como fazer, tentarei aqui novamente

Answer (score 1):

Veja se é isso que precisa. Leia os comentários no código e, se tiver alguma dúvida, só perguntar. Esta é apenas uma das formas de se resolver seu problema.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Usuario um = new Usuario("Yuri", "12345");
        int tentativa = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String usuarioDigitado, senhaDigitada;
        int numeroMaximoTentativas = 5;

        //O laço será executado enquanto não for atingido
        //o número máximo de tentativas
        while(tentativa < numeroMaximoTentativas) {
            tentativa++;
            System.out.println("Qual o usuario?");
            usuarioDigitado = s.nextLine();

            if(!usuarioDigitado.equals(um.getUsuario())) {
                System.out.println("Usuário incorreto");
            }

            System.out.println("Qual a senha?");
            senhaDigitada = s.nextLine();

            if(!senhaDigitada.equals(um.getSenha())) {
                System.out.println("Senha incorreta");
            }

            if(usuarioDigitado.equals(um.getUsuario()) &&
                    senhaDigitada.equals(um.getSenha())) {
                System.out.println("Usuário logado com sucesso");
                //Se usuário e senha batem, quebramos o laço
                break;
            }

            //Enquanto ainda houver tentativa, a mensagem é mostrada
            if(tentativa < numeroMaximoTentativas) {
                System.out.println("Restam " + (numeroMaximoTentativas - tentativa) + " tentativas...");
            }

            if(tentativa == numeroMaximoTentativas) {
                System.out.println("Você excedeu o limite de erros!! Finalizando...");
            }
        }
    }
}

class Usuario {
    private String usuario;
    private String senha;

    public Usuario(String usuario, String senha) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
}
```